Operator less than a projection with equal trace?
If $A$ is an operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $P$ is a projection on $H$ with $0 \leq A \leq P$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(A) = \operatorname{Tr}(P)$, then $A = P$.
My proof:
Since $0 \leq A \leq P$, we have $P-A \geq 0$.
Then $\operatorname{Tr}(P-A) = \operatorname{Tr}(P) - \operatorname{Tr}(A) = 0$, so we have $P-A = 0$, which implies $A = P$.
Is this correct? I believe that a positive operator with trace 0 must be the zero operator, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.
Edit: as was pointed out, we require that $H$ be finite-dimensional.
Edit 2: I misunderstood the comments...we do not require $H$ be finite-dimensional, we require $\operatorname{Tr}(P) < \infty$.

Indeed, a positive operator with zero trace must be the zero operator, and this argument works assuming $\text{Tr}(P) < \infty$. (If $\text{Tr}(P) = \infty$, i.e., $PH$ has infinite dimensions, then the result would be false in the first place.)

Thank you! :) :)

You don't require that $H$ is finite-dimensional. What you require is that $\operatorname{Tr}(P)<\infty$.

Fixed, ty! :) :)

Yes, though $P$ being a projection is irrelevant.
As you say, the relevant fact is that the trace is faithful: if $T\geq0$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(T)=0$, then $T=0$. The proof is simply to notice that for a fixed orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ you have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(T)=\sum_n\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle=\sum_n\|T^{1/2}e_n\|^2,
$$
so $T^{1/2}e_n=0$ for all $n$, and then $Te_n=0$ for all $n$. Thus $T=0$.
Note that to apply this it is crucial that $\operatorname{Tr}(P)<\infty$, for otherwise you cannot apply the linearity of the trace.

Thank you! :) :)
